# Can I trust this weird BIOS Message ending in 'thanks'?

Tags: bios, ac-adapter

So I started up my laptop today and was greeted with the following message (not a direct quote):

```
The type of the AC adapter cannot be determined. This may interfere with your 
computer's performance. Try unplugging the AC adapter and then plugging it 
back in, thanks.
```

The problem was that I hadn't fully secured the plug into the back of the computer. However, I was a little taken aback when a message from BIOS said, "thanks."

Is this normal? Any chance the message was illegitimate (virus)?

Comment: Probably wasn't written by a native English speaker.

Comment: what sort of laptop?

Comment: @journeymanGeek Dell Inspiron N7010

Comment: Yep, your AC adapter has a virus.

Comment: "[Are you sure to continue? (y/n)](http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22Are+you+sure+to+continue%22)" :)

Comment: @josh If you can't get a compatible, yet "non-dell" power supply, perhaps try wiggling the D/C power connector while power cycling, to see if you can get the message again.  Note: This is a Bad Idea, for many reasons. :)

Comment: I like it when ROM coders write polite messages.  It's so rare that it's wonderful, especially when it looks like they're struggling a little bit with the English language.  =)

Comment: @techie007 What are you even talking about?

Comment: Sorry Josh, it was a little joke about how common slightly-incorrect, translated English is in the computer world (as Shinrai points out). :)  Similar to the "thanks".

Answer (score 3):

The Dell AC Adapters have a specific module which communicates with the motherboard in order to verify you are using a "real" Dell Adapter.

When you are using a non-Dell adapter, or when your adapter has its chip toasted, or when your motherboard has its chip toasted, or when your adapter is loosely connected you get this message.
The consequence is that your laptop is powered but the battery will not charge.

Comment: I understand that, but isn't it a little odd that it uses the wording, "thanks." ?

Comment: It's less odd than a BIOS that says "Please to be prepare for updating of BIOS flash", which is verbatim one I've seen before. :)  Practically speaking, most of these things are written by Asian engineers who *don't speak very good English*. You're being paranoid.

Comment: My favourite is from a Phoenix BIOS on an XT computer (8088 CPU) in the 1980s that appeared when there was no keyboard connected; it went something like this:  **Keyboard not installed.  Press F2 to continue.**

Comment: thats common, what they mean is plug in a keyboard and press f2. Modern systems still do this if you have halt on keyboard error turned on

Comment: `but isn't it a little odd that it uses the wording, "thanks."?`   Sadly yes; we have become accustomed to terseness in technology (to the point that to us devs, it actually gets to feel “correct” to speak frankly).     `most of these things are written by Asian engineers who don't speak very good English.`   I’ve never understood that; it’s not like there are no fluent bilingual people in China, Japan, etc. Why cannot a *company* hire someone whose sole job it is to be a proof-reader‽ `o.O`